# Mozilla firefox "The connection was reset" on google results

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, google-search

When I search for something on Google (which is mostly about programming and computers etc.), it shows some results. But when I click on them, or open them in a New Tab, I see this error on Mozilla Firefox (v 35.0.1):

[image: The connection was reset.]

The url is something like :

> http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjI1omtxtvKAhWV1I4KHf25Cy4QFggtMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsuperuser.com%2Fquestions%2F648478%2Fmaking-a-win-xp-laptop-a-wifi-hotspot&usg=AFQjCNHjKEGIGNpBIiRH_-8oqW3S48yxzQ&sig2=t0uig3cJS_RqCQwqvweiyA&bvm=bv.113034660,d.c2E

Now,

- I delete the `http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjI1omtxtvKAhWV1I4KHf25Cy4QFggtMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2F` at the beginning.
- I delete the `&usg=AFQjCNHjKEGIGNpBIiRH_-8oqW3S48yxzQ&sig2=t0uig3cJS_RqCQwqvweiyA&bvm=bv.113034660,d.c2E` at the end.
- I convert all the `%2F`s to `/`s

So, what's left is:

> superuser.com/questions/648478/making-a-win-xp-laptop-a-wifi-hotspot

Then, when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it opens the page.

This occurs:

- Every time I have a stackoverflow.com link
- Often on superuser.com links
- And sometimes on other links.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You're using the `.co.in` TLD (which is the TLD assigned to India).  Are you in India?  And are you behind a firewall that is blocking that TLD?  If so, then you will get the normal "Your connection was reset" error because the firewall is going to terminate the connection.

Comment: Yes I am in India. And no, other `.co.in` links open easily.

Comment: I get that sometimes too, not sure why. You could try an addon for fixing Google results links: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-no-tracking-url/

Comment: @MC10 That is not available for v 35.0.1

Comment: Previous versions can be found here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-no-tracking-url/versions/ You could try version Version 1.3.1.1-signed.